# Error-detecting Self-repairing Program

Tags: code-golf, source-layout, radiation-hardening, error-correction

Your task is to create a program where if any one character is deleted, it will detect which character was deleted and then re-insert the deleted character in its own source file.

For instance, if your program is `RadiationHardened` and it is modified to `RadiaionHardened`, then your program must output that the 5th byte (0-indexed) was modified and then the program source must be `RadiationHardened` immediately after execution.

### Notes and rules

- You may assume that exactly one character was deleted in the source code before execution. Behavior for the unmodified program is undefined.
- You may assume the changed byte will be deleted, not transposed, inserted, or replaced.
- In the case of a run of multiple of the same character, you may report either the first or the last index of the run, but be consistent about which you use. For example `baaad` being deleted to `baad` can report either 1 or 3 (zero indexed), but must be the same throughout the entire program.
- You do not need to write out the entire source to its own file. You need only re-insert the deleted byte.
- Unlike the typical rules for radiation-hardened quines, detecting the changed byte from reading the program's own source code is fair game.
- You can output the changed byte index through any reasonable format. Be consistent about whether it is 0-indexed or 1-indexed or any other notation. You may even output a number within a template string.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest program wins.

Good luck!

EDIT1: changed requirement from replacement to deletion

EDIT2: added rule for runs of duplicates

Comment: This is a lot harder than handling arbitrary _deletions_. Most non-esolangs are obviously out (it's usually impossible to write _any_ program that remains syntactially valid under _any_ one-byte modification). Even Fungeoids are mostly thwarted (they can't do anything if the 0th byte is changed into a _quit program_ command). I thought maybe one of two IPs could survive in something like [Fission](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission) but its `*` command kills all of the IPs. [Cardinal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal) can't do it either, because of `@`.

Comment: This might be turned into a `code-challenge` where each program is allowed to declare a list of bytes that are protected against radiation (but no more than -- say -- 50% of the total size). A simple scoring system could be to count each radiation-protected byte as 10 bytes, or something like that.

Comment: (But that may lead to some trivial and not very interesting answers.)

Comment: This sounds impossible in most, if not all, languages.

Comment: I'm considering switching this to deletions. Arnauld's suggestion is also viable.

Comment: One trivial way would be to wrap the code in a try-except, where only those keywords cannot be mutated...

Comment: @JoKing, reporting either as missing is fine, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: @Lynn (Under the original modification version). *In theory* Runic could survive, as there's no equivalent command to Fission's `*`, but Runic is *terrible* at reading its own source (I have yet to work out a single-IP multi-line quine, which would need to be the basis). I'm also not sure how the program is supposed to both output the changed index *and* the altered character's index. (Runic has no file io).

Comment: i am assuming we cannot consider machines with error-correcting memory built in, otherwise it seems like the single byte program '0' would be valid in 05ab1e

Comment: @donbright I don't think that would fulfil the repairing the source code part of the challenge

Comment: "You may require the file to be named a certain name and be run from a specific directory" - be careful, someone can just require that the filename be the correct program...

Answer (score 11):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>344 296</s> 248 bytes

```
20020xxnngg33%%!!2200gg''00--3300gg33%%!!4400gg55%%!!22kk++55##rr55kk::00gg\\11pp00gg\\11++11pp22++00::pp00gg\\11++00gg--!!zz!!22**++00::gg00gg8844**--!!55++jj..''gg::00rr00::gg\\--..''220011''0011::''002211''223311''00441144kkppgg11001100::99oo@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsMgEETv/QsJQVAM7qqQeMqHeCqkCxESEQohP2@7SKGnnX0zDPPcXu@DNrPMraG1aK/rOIicG0ch8EuIpLTWGOdYd@496xB6JmetQxiGWkPIOUb2UgIo5ae05g9Ra2tj/OesjBHivrlJqZ4gYj7P3ivFbgha7/s0SUnE/bX2VErGMOWdALwTIEa@iPwjOte59wDe51wKEQDnuGFZznNdH619AA)

[Verification!](https://tio.run/##dVFdj9owEHzGv8IEISeYhDgfElhCOrXv/QMHqgI4xpdiR04ox1X97dR7SYCH61N2Z2bHO5v62h6NTm83daqNbbFpUF811wah2hppixNeQxs17UHpyIri4AeoVL@ELk7Ccd7IA6nSrU@@XVuB9@asW07m2En83iMSem8OwidFs1eKBEHQj/R8gNBBlNie9c8euTMcjS6qPWJTO7vh3TkmFxLgosGl40dldLGqFQ@3kRXt2WqXKKq7QW9h6naxE@VZSxGuloud0otyt1OY/Blc/xIvGBKiiTm3Lt5XK6FJn/eHwftj4QwhrtPfmc/aRRS/vx8L62wIQcp9YlQaixVWGluY859uFEBUVeK@fVVbPF7jwQNi/nejV6629D5HGd@6E4y6VbzpAfvTJuDe1Ffzh3kwd3ZzBcKiaYT76cPieL3GysFfnJ3Yp6sPc2V/M5jr/T9fv4d/POoCYrrGDN1uSRwn8fu71lKm6XQ6HicOkZKQOA7DNIW6w7MM6jzvNFVFaZ5PJtbmeVVxDtxmw1hdDxWl0CUJpXHM@TMOVRiOxx8f4DSbdQopAV8us2w2AzbPKX17iyJCpAR/azvVZhOGgMKejMGejHEO3ySBPknStMOzjLEsq6q6lpIx0IHDamXMywv6Bw)

Befunge-98 is the first esoteric language that I could find that was both 2D and had file output. This is a full solution (with a trailing newline) stored in a file named as a tab character. It outputs as 0-indexed, and outputs the first index in a run of characters (though there's only ever pairs).

There's a few golfs to be made, <s>especially as there are 15 no-ops in the code</s>, now just one no-op! I will be working on making this shorter, with the goal of getting to or below 200 bytes.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't think this was possible

Answer (score 6):

## [Unefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 118 bytes

```
22xx00##rr33kk::gg\\11--pp22++00ppgg\\11++gg--!!zz!!22**--00gg::gg8844**--!!22++jj##''rr++..gg''2200pp0011--00::99oo@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoQwEATfEnIIOIy0o4ckJx/i1R1Q0CEguH4@kt1bd1HUdayf69CVU2T7/matIvcNeF/KOO57zqrLMgzMZiJEgNmfEKkyO/c8zol0HTOg2vwYp6n9xom2zfsQSiHqe9UQRFoDaE0g55TOc55rfQE)

[Verification!](https://tio.run/##dZLBjpswEIbP8VNMQJFhCYiQPSRISNv2VKnqodfdqHLBgHcb2zJmk2zVZ8@OE0i2UnrCeP75Zv7x6INtlVwej2KrlbGgOjKcukNHiDaqMWwLhftNOlsJmRjOqiAktfjNJdtyjHkTz0mFtAH9fLAcStVLm9M5oCQYGAmXpap4QFlXCkHDMBxShnhISMVrML38OdxcIjmZ7IRtQWnEjXXnQHc0BNZBndfJzgjLr6iJ4bY3Eu0k@pzl6UPdy4ZDHKONYr2CeAH0z0j7S71wdEZ81Vu0dasV4g8@vysoW4ZAZxP1l8jpjNb465eWGcRQSgR@UuLDN6U0qFdugLOydQDDSssNqZUBAUKCccjgw9hC596HrzXYll8zQHQglQXN3KPVwFy37nBRdGQiahgoj2ID0wLGrhCJzB@Y4aDCGFYJZnk1yjH83xE85mITXbDRIt/guCdn796sgmDWhbk3C8T8WjucI24uwlPZT13HsWnbMnsqjyGNxdDQqRlZ8b0z8o9dTGTntHHEUBQgbvLck0KLe/GLcxwo10wYXqH0xg5RM64QxscS9bAIrsR1IB9e9GoMZwxRAQtyPGbZfp@mvm/McvnykudN8/S0WMSx1lkWRWmq9fkmipomjqfTt7fpNMvu7uI4TZvG6Ver@3v37@6j6PnZ9yk1JoqSpGkozTLHSFPHTNM8X6@Venh4Bw)

While golfing my Befunge-98 answer, I realised I could save some bytes by porting it over to Unefunge, since I would only have to worry about the one dimension rather than the two. This also opened up a lot of possible shortcuts and golfs, which made the new solution much *much* smaller.

#### Explanation (de-duplicated):

```
2x        Set the delta of the movement to 2
          This means the pointer moves 2 cells every step
          This will also initialise a counter as 2 (unless a 2 has been removed)
  0       Create the cell counter  (This will be stored at cell 0)
   #r     Enter the loop
     3k:                 Create 3 more copies of the counter
        g                Get the cell at the counter's position
         \1-p            Put it in the cell before that position
             2+0p        Add 2 to the counter and put it in cell 0
                 g       Get the cell at the counter's position
                  \1+g   Get the next cell
                      -!z!2*      If they are identical, push two, else 0
                            --    Subtract it from the total counter
                              0g:g84*-!   If the next character is a space
                                       2+j  r   Exit loop
                                         j#'    Else jump back to the start

Once the loop is over
+      Add the negative counter to the total counter
 .     And print
   '20p          Replace the 2 in cell 0 that was overwritten
             o   Write to a file named
            9    Tab
       01-       The cells from -1 to
  g              The total number of cells
              @  And exit the program
```